# ''Can I take your umbrella I haven't brought mine with me.''true or wrong?

Tags: grammar

Can I take your umbrella I haven't brought mine with ... .

> 1.me
>
> 2.mine
>
> 3.my
>
> 4.myself

It is clear that 2 and 3 are false but I doubt between 1 and 4.I think I have heared the first one but the forth one seems OK.So what is the right answer?

Comment: Remember this: **myself** = "alone, unaided" (I did it myself) or "my physical person" (I dressed myself)  or "my mind/my time" (I don't know what to do with myself). **me** = the person you (the listener) are looking at or listening to.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know (I am a learner),there are two situations in which you should be careful when using reflexive pronouns:

1. When using prepositions referring to a place
2. When using **with** with the meaning of "accompanied by"

In the two situations above, you must avoid using reflexive pronoun. Therefore, I would choose **me**.

Also, I am not sure why you want to add that prepositional phrase to the sentence; it sounds redundant to my learner ears.

Comment: "I haven't brought mine *with me*" is 100% idiomatic and means "I have one, but I did not bring it."  The emphasis is on the neglect or the forgetfulness.